# How to display names in a method of a class (ruby)?

Tags: ruby

I learn the class with ruby and I have a question here.
I want to change the name of @name, like this ...

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
      @name = name
  end

  def say_hello(a_user)
      puts "The user #{@name} say hello at #{@name} !"
   end

end
```

What I have

```
[1] pry(main)> user1 = User.new("Joe")
=> #<User:0x000055ebac183358 @name="Joe">
[2] pry(main)> user2 = User.new("Luis")
=> #<User:0x000055ebac11cb80 @name="Luis">
[3] pry(main)> user1.say_hello(user2)

=> The user Joe say hello at Joe !
```

And What I expect

```
=> The user Joe say hello at Luis !
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this if I understand your problem correctly.

```rb
class User
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def say_hello(user)
    puts "The person #{@name} say hello at #{user.name} !"
  end
end
```